# Azure - Automatically add new Appservice to Frontdoor

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-front-door

We are deploying a lot of Appservices in Azure trough Azure Devops in different pipelines. For each Appservice we deploy a West and a North Europe instance. We would like to add them automatically to Azure Fontdoor (with ARM template) with a frontend domain. We have ARM templates in place (the default one from Microsoft) but the template is not incremental. So when we add one the allready configured ones dissapear.

Any idea how we can add Appservices one by one to Frontdoor without having the full list off appservices available?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `ARM template deployment` task.  This task supports incremental deployment of app service.

I use the `azuredeploy.parameters.json` file to input the parameters.

Here is the example:

[image]

Then I use this file in the `ARM template deployment` task and select the `incremental` option.

For the first time, you can directly use the parameters in the file.

[image: Task Settings]

For the next time, you could add custom parameters to the `Override template parameters` field.

[image: Add parameters]

Result:

[image]

App service will not be overwritten.

Hope this helps.